# Migrate from github enterprise to github.com

Tags: github, migration

We have a few repositories and forks on a trial version of Github Enterprise. I want to evaluate how to migrate from Github enterprise to Github.com (into a paid for organization, say)

The only resource I found was how to perform the migration in the opposite direction
https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.0/admin/articles/moving-a-repository-from-github-com-to-github-enterprise/

I have contacted github.com asking the same questions as below and I am waiting for their response.

- How do we migrate a repository from github Enterprise to github.com? (fairly certain that a git clone --bare and a git push --mirror will do the job)
- If I migrate forks as well, how do we make sure that the relationship between the original and forks is maintained?
- How do I migrate the webhooks and services we configured for our repositories?
- How do I transfer the Pull requests/Issues? (article I linked to above says we need to use the Github API, I am OK with this solution)
- Can we migrate teams and users? (guessing, probably not)

Note that we have the backups of the enterprise instance performed using the backup tools provided by github (I think it is called ghe-backup)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the steps in the linked document in the reverse order as well:

- Create an empty repository at github.com
- Create a clone of the enterprise repository on your local.
- Add github.com as a remote reference on your local clone.
- Push all references to the github.com repository.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.alexhadik.com/blog/2016/5/26/migrating-github-repositories-with-gitmover appears to offer a solution: [GitMover](https://github.com/ahadik/git_mover) is "a simple Python script that takes Git repos on any type of GitHub installation, and copies issues, labels and milestones from one to the other. It's the perfect tool to help automate the open-sourcing of an internal project."