# Migrate repository from GitHub Enterprise to GitHub

Tags: github, migration, github-api, github-enterprise

I want to migrate a repository from GitHub Enterprise to GitHub.

Documentation on how to move vice versa is [quite extensive](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.8/admin/guides/migrations/).

Moving "in my direction", however, only seems to be covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753111/migrate-from-github-enterprise-to-github-com). The answer there only says how to migrate commits/branches, which is only part of what I need.

Is there a way to migrate the whole repository, including at least all issues, from GitHub Enterprise (v2.8) to GitHub? Ideally, all authors should be referenced to the according users on GitHub.

There seems to be an API, both for [GitHub Enterprise](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.8/v3/) and for [GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/). It seems to be an option to write a script that e.g. manually retrieves all issues from GitHub Enterpise and puts then on GitHub. If that is the case, does anybody aware of a script that already does this?

Comment: 6 years later and still nobody knows....